# Using subprocess to run an executable with multiple parameters

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

The command line looks like this:

`cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\COM`

`snapshot.exe -Publisher [publisher] -PublisherDB [TEST] -Distributor [dist] -Publication [merge] -ReplicationType 2 -DistributorSecurityMode 1`

So two commands in total

so far I have had some luck with:

```
subprocess.run(["C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\150\\COM\\snapshot.exe","-Publisher [publisher] -PublisherDB [TEST] -Distributor [dist] -Publication [merge] -ReplicationType 2 -DistributorSecurityMode 1"])
```

This runs the snapshot.exe but says `-Publisher [publisher] -PublisherDB [TEST] -Distributor [dist] -Publication [merge] -ReplicationType 2 -DistributorSecurityMode 1"]` is not a valid parameter.

Comment: I expect each argument to snapshot.exe  needs to be a separate entry in the array, viz,
`subprocess.run(["C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\150\\COM\\snapshot.exe","-Publisher","[publisher]", "-PublisherDB", "[TEST]", "-Distributor", "[dist]", "-Publication", "[merge]", "-ReplicationType", "2", "-DistributorSecurityMode", "1"])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each separate string needs to be a separate string in the call to `run`, too.

The `cd` might not be necessary (most sensible tools don't care which directory they run in) but I'll add a `cwd` parameter too just to show how it can all be done in a single call.

```py
subprocess.run(
        ["C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\150\\COM\\snapshot.exe"
        "-Publisher", "[publisher]", "-PublisherDB", "[TEST]",
        "-Distributor", "[dist]", "-Publication", "[merge]",
        "-ReplicationType", "2", "-DistributorSecurityMode", "1"],
    # probably drop this
    cwd="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\150\\COM",
    # probably add this
    check=True)
```